# Android display permissions with description and sections

Tags: android, android-listview, permissions, sections

I wanna display apk's permission list with sections in my app like google play store. I had a list of permissions and how can i display descriptions instead of "android.permission...." to user in order to increase usability? Thanks in Advance!

[image]